Why the app store connect reject cannot connect to the api?
when i try the app in debug and in testflight with iphone and with VPN it is working well but in the app review they cannot connect to the api the api is http i made in the info plist to allow arbitrary loads to allow the http but we got the same error message that in the photo

what is port 65387 that in the photo? why they cannot connect to the api
